# How to get a first and last value for each partition in a column using SQL

Tags: sql, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, hiveql, window-functions

I have the dataset looks like below.

```
         ts                c1           c2               c3
2019-01-04T01:50:00.000Z    C   25.48801612854004   33.317527770996094
2019-01-04T01:51:00.000Z    C   25.74610710144043   33.392295837402344
2019-01-04T01:52:00.000Z    C   25.978872299194336  33.29177474975586
2019-01-04T01:53:00.000Z    B   26.12158203125      33.2805061340332
2019-01-04T01:54:00.000Z    B   26.28511619567871   33.26923751831055
2019-01-04T01:55:00.000Z    C   26.470335006713867  33.25796890258789
2019-01-04T01:56:00.000Z    C   26.63957977294922   33.24669647216797
2019-01-04T01:57:00.000Z    C   26.954004287719727  33.23542785644531
2019-01-04T01:58:00.000Z    C   27.08258056640625   33.224159240722656
2019-01-04T01:59:00.000Z    A   27.25551986694336   33.212890625
2019-01-04T02:00:00.000Z    A   27.514263153076172  33.201622009277344
2019-01-04T02:01:00.000Z    A   27.588970184326172  33.17148971557617
2019-01-04T02:02:00.000Z    B   27.727638244628906  33.13819122314453
2019-01-04T02:03:00.000Z    B   27.956039428710938  33.104896545410156
2019-01-04T02:04:00.000Z    B   28.152463912963867  33.10499954223633
```

I want to take the first and last value of "ts" for every partition values from column "c1".
I have tried the below query but it doesn't return the correct results.

```
SELECT ts, c1, c2, c3,
first_value(ts) OVER (partition by c1 order by ts
ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as first,
last_value(ts) OVER (partition by c1 order by ts
ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as last
FROM `default`.`a07_a15`
```

Issue: First value returns only three distinct ts value and max value returns completely wrong.

Expected: I need the first and last value for every repeated partition values.

```
         ts                c1           c2               c3                 first                last
2019-01-04T01:50:00.000Z    C   25.48801612854004   33.317527770996094  2019-01-04T01:50:00.000Z    2019-01-04T01:52:00.000Z
2019-01-04T01:51:00.000Z    C   25.74610710144043   33.392295837402344  2019-01-04T01:50:00.000Z    2019-01-04T01:52:00.000Z
2019-01-04T01:52:00.000Z    C   25.978872299194336  33.29177474975586   2019-01-04T01:50:00.000Z    2019-01-04T01:52:00.000Z
2019-01-04T01:53:00.000Z    B   26.12158203125      33.2805061340332    2019-01-04T01:53:00.000Z    2019-01-04T01:54:00.000Z
2019-01-04T01:54:00.000Z    B   26.28511619567871   33.26923751831055   2019-01-04T01:53:00.000Z    2019-01-04T01:54:00.000Z
2019-01-04T01:55:00.000Z    C   26.470335006713867  33.25796890258789   2019-01-04T01:55:00.000Z    2019-01-04T01:58:00.000Z
2019-01-04T01:56:00.000Z    C   26.63957977294922   33.24669647216797   2019-01-04T01:55:00.000Z    2019-01-04T01:58:00.000Z
2019-01-04T01:57:00.000Z    C   26.954004287719727  33.23542785644531   2019-01-04T01:55:00.000Z    2019-01-04T01:58:00.000Z    
2019-01-04T01:58:00.000Z    C   27.08258056640625   33.224159240722656  2019-01-04T01:55:00.000Z    2019-01-04T01:58:00.000Z
2019-01-04T01:59:00.000Z    A   27.25551986694336   33.212890625        2019-01-04T01:59:00.000Z    2019-01-04T02:01:00.000Z
2019-01-04T02:00:00.000Z    A   27.514263153076172  33.201622009277344  2019-01-04T01:59:00.000Z    2019-01-04T02:01:00.000Z
2019-01-04T02:01:00.000Z    A   27.588970184326172  33.17148971557617   2019-01-04T01:59:00.000Z    2019-01-04T02:01:00.000Z
2019-01-04T02:02:00.000Z    B   27.727638244628906  33.13819122314453   2019-01-04T02:02:00.000Z    2019-01-04T02:04:00.000Z
2019-01-04T02:03:00.000Z    B   27.956039428710938  33.104896545410156  2019-01-04T02:02:00.000Z    2019-01-04T02:04:00.000Z
2019-01-04T02:04:00.000Z    B   28.152463912963867  33.10499954223633   2019-01-04T02:02:00.000Z    2019-01-04T02:04:00.000Z
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `lag()` and `lead()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(c1) over (order by ts) as prev_c1,
             lead(c1) over (order by ts) as next_c1
      from t
     ) t
where prev_c1 is null or next_c1 is null or
      prev_c1 <> c1 or next_c1 <> c1;
```

This puts the values in different rows.  If you want them in the same rows, probably treating this as a gaps-and-islands problem is the simplest solution:

```
select c1, min(ts), max(ts)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by ts) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by c1 order by ts) as seqnum_2
      from t
     ) t
group by c1, (seqnum - seqnum_2);
```

EDIT:

If you need to keep the original rows, just use window functions, make sure aliases match:

```
select t.*,
       min(ts) over (partition by c1, (seqnum - seqnum2)) as min_ts,
       max(ts) over (partition by c1, (seqnum - seqnum2)) as max_ts
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by ts) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by c1 order by ts) as seqnum2
      from t
     ) t
```

Comment: @Linoff the above solution works fine(2nd one). But I want to include all the available columns in the dataset (ts, c1, c2, and c3). Let's say we have 4 rows in the first partition we need to put the same constant value (first and last) for the 4 rows and so on

Comment: @Sudha . . . The first one keeps all columns for both the first and last rows.

Comment: @Linoff sorry, I've tried but it's not working as expected. We need a min and Max of "ts" value but it returns partition value. Kindly check the expected output I've edited in the above post.

Comment: @Sudha . . . That is really a tweak on the query.  You don't need the aggregation, just window functions.

Comment: Great!. Now it's working as expected. Thanks a lot @Linoff.